# tSQLt.Fail does not make test fail

Tags: tsqlt

I created a test like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyTestClass.[test example01] AS
BEGIN
    EXEC tSQLt.Fail 'Not implemented';
END;
```

However, when I run the test the result is Success. What am I doing wrong? I am using v1.0.7950.1808.

Comment: How are you creating the test class? How are you executing the test? What is the exact output you’re getting?

Comment: The problem has fixed itself.  Instead of RunAll, I executed RunTestClass 'MyTestClass', which included only this test. The test results showed 'Failure' in the Results column. I then tried RunAll again and it worked i.e.,  'Failure' in the Results column for this test and the expected Failure or Success for the other tests.

Comment: I had another problem that fixed itself before this one. The output of RunAll was showing each test multiple times. I ran an arbitrary test by itself and the output had just one row. I went back to RunAll and then each test appeared only once in the output.